# Replace character inside a String with a variable Python

Tags: python, string, replace

I have a String and I need to change a character inside it every loop with a variable

I've being trying to use .replace and .format to do it, but something is wrong.

```
searchlink = "https://acervo.estadao.com.br/procura/#!/ministro/Acervo//spo/2/2000/2003//Primeira"
x = 2

for y in range(10):
    x += 1
    i = x - 1
    global searchlink
    searchlink = (searchlink.replace('/{}/', '/{}/').format(i, x))
```

Comment: Why not just `i = "2"` and `x = "3"`? And what about `y`?

Comment: What should the string look like at the end?

Comment: Can you give a couple of examples of the URL with the changed digits?

Comment: Because I need to add a number to it every loop, and I can't add a number to a string. So i need to make it a number, add what i want and then transform it in a string again, so i can use as a string.

Comment: Basically, the `format` is in the wrong place (your are formatting the result of the replacement, not the patterns to be replaced).

Comment: In this example it would be like this:
https://acervo.estadao.com.br/procura/#!/ministro/Acervo//spo/3/2000/2003//Primeira
https://acervo.estadao.com.br/procura/#!/ministro/Acervo//spo/4/2000/2003//Primeira
https://acervo.estadao.com.br/procura/#!/ministro/Acervo//spo/5/2000/2003//Primeira

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the order of operations wrong in your string formatting code. You want to do the formatting on the strings you're passing to `replace`, but currently you have it in the other order (you do the replace call with the `'/{}/'` strings, which is useless, then try to format later).

Try `searchlink = searchlink.replace('/{}/'.format(i), '/{}/'.format(x))`

Note that this will work even if `i` and `x` are integers, so you may not need to call `str` on them earlier in the code.